# Why is the built-in python sum function behaving like this?

Tags: python, pearson-correlation

I am trying to write a program that determines the pearson correlation coefficient with population standard deviation in python. I thought this would be pretty trivial until I got to the part where I was summing (yi -  μy)*(xi -  μx). Here is my full code:

```
def r(x, y):
    mx, my = sum(x) / len(x), sum(y) / len(y)
    sdx, sdy = (sum([(xi-mx)**2 for xi in x]) / len(x))**0.5, (sum([(yi- 
    my)**2 for yi in y]) / (len(y)))**0.5
    res = ((sum([(xi-mx)*(yi-my) for xi in x for yi in y]))/(len(x)*sdx*sdy))**0.5
    return res
```

I noticed the result was super small, so I checked out the sum of (xi-mx):

```
sum([(xi-mx) for xi in x])
```

and the result was -9.769962616701378e-15. Here are the values in the list:

```
print([(xi-mx) for xi in x])
[3.2699999999999987, 3.0699999999999994, 1.2699999999999987, 1.0699999999999985, 0.9699999999999989, 0.2699999999999987, -0.7300000000000013, -1.7300000000000013, -2.7300000000000013, -4.730000000000001]
```

Can anyone explain why python is behaving so strangely with this?

Comment: Rounding point error. That's all there is to it. Use `round(number, decimal_points)` if needed.

Comment: Did you see the `e-15` on the end?

Comment: @GeeTransit rounding xi to 4 decimal places still returns -9.769962616701378e-15... i thought this would fix a potential floating point error as well and idk why it won't work

Comment: Hmm. what was the `x` and `y` values you used to call the function with? I'm going to see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah every result is followed by e and a negative integer

Comment: Okay, sounds like you don't know what that means. That's (a form of) scientific notation. It means "times 10^-15".

Comment: @GeeTransit `10 9.8 8 7.8 7.7 7 6 5 4 2` 
`200 44 32 24 22 17 15 12 8 4`

Comment: @user2357112 no i know what that means it's just not the right answer considering the actual sum of the list is nowhere near that small

Comment: Go back and check your arithmetic. The sum is, in fact, that small. It'd be 0 if it weren't for rounding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
res = (sum([(xi-mx)*(yi-my) for xi in x for yi in y]))/(len(x)*sdx*sdy)
```

That isn't doing what you think it does. When calculating the numerator of Pearson's correlation coefficient, `(xi - mx) * (yi - my)` should be paired sequentially.
Using [`zip`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) should fix it.

```
res = (sum([(xi-mx)*(yi-my) for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]))/(len(x)*sdx*sdy)
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
def r(x, y):
    mx, my = sum(x) / len(x), sum(y) / len(y)
    sdx, sdy = (sum([(xi-mx)**2 for xi in x]) / len(x))**0.5, (sum([(yi-
    my)**2 for yi in y]) / (len(y)))**0.5
    res = (sum([(xi-mx)*(yi-my) for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]))/(len(x)*sdx*sdy)
    return res

r(x, y) # 0.6124721937208479
```

---

What does `for xi in x for yi in y` really do?

```
>>> x, y = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
>>> [(xi, yi) for xi in x for yi in y]
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

So there's repetition going on. (Actually generating a list of combinations.) You can use `zip` to aggregate values into pairs:

```
>>> [*zip(x, y)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for! program worked after i changed that. i figured i made a math error but it was just me writing that poorly. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The sum of the numbers you showed is in fact close to 0.  Why is that strange?  In fact, it *must* be close to 0.  Regardless of the values in x to begin with, mathematically

```
sum(xi - mean(x) for xi in x) =
sum(xi for xi in x) - sum(mean(x) for xi in x) =
len(x) * mean(x) - len(x) * mean(x) =
0
```

That the numeric result isn't exactly 0 is simply due to floating-point rounding errors.